# VisibleForTesting annotation for C++

Tags: c++

Is there an annotation in C++ similar to `@VisibleForTesting` in [Java](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html)? I tried to google around, but could not find a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward declare your test class/method as a friend of the class being tested.

**Update:** Adding example.

```
class type_to_test
{
    friend class test_case_class;
};

class test_case_class
{
public:
    test_case_class()
    {
        type_to_test tt;
        // everything in tt should be accessible here or in any other member function if you can grab hold of an instance.
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please share an example of what you mean?